# python: how to implement a matrix as column1=x column2=x^2... columnP=x^p

Tags: python, numpy, loops, matrix

I want to create a matrix that has as many columns as the given input(for ex: p). and those columns will be the powered values of the first array. i'm using a dataset like this:

```
with open("dataset.csv") as f:
dataset = list(csv.reader(f))
for a in dataset:
    arr = np.append(arr, int(a[0]))  # arr = 1,1,2,3,3,3,3...
    one_list = np.append(one_list, 1)
x = np.column_stack((one_list, arr))
```

and I want the matrix like this if p=3:

```
x = [[1, 1, 1, 1]
     [1, 1, 1, 1]
     [1, 2, 4, 8]
     [1, 3, 9, 27]
      ...]
```

update: I solved it like this:

```
a = 2
p = 3

for i in range(p-1):
  arr1 = np.power(arr, a)
  a += 1
  x = np.column_stack((x, arr1))
```

the results are true but it looks like this if i enter p=4 or more:

```
[[1.0000e+00 1.0000e+00 1.0000e+00 1.0000e+00 1.0000e+00 1.0000e+00
  1.0000e+00]
 [1.0000e+00 1.0000e+00 1.0000e+00 1.0000e+00 1.0000e+00 1.0000e+00
  1.0000e+00]
 [1.0000e+00 2.0000e+00 4.0000e+00 8.0000e+00 1.6000e+01 3.2000e+01
  6.4000e+01]
 [1.0000e+00 2.0000e+00 4.0000e+00 8.0000e+00 1.6000e+01 3.2000e+01
  6.4000e+01]
 [1.0000e+00 2.0000e+00 4.0000e+00 8.0000e+00 1.6000e+01 3.2000e+01
  6.4000e+01]...
```

how can I have a matrix without all those zeros like I mentioned above? any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: What have you tried, why did it fail? I see the tag `numpy` - looks like a broadcasting exercise.

Comment: edited, you can see my implementation

Comment: Thank you for adding the code. Can you explain, what's the problem with it? Does it produce the wrong result?

Comment: it produces a strange matrix which doesn't look like the example output that I wanted. there are values like 43046721, 65536. I don't know where they're coming from...

Comment: wrt your update: `a` is not needed use `i` instead. be sure to initialize `arr` and `x` to some default before your for loop. do you ask why your array if floats is represented in exponential notation?

Comment: yes, the values dont look 1,2,.. they look like 1.0000e+00 2.0000e+00.. I couldn't figure out why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. numpy broadcasting

The function you are looking for is `np.cumprod()`. Be sure to use the `axis` parameter. The initial matrix is build using *broadcasting*.

```
import numpy as np

p = 4
arr = np.r_[1,2,3]

np.cumprod(arr[:,np.newaxis]*np.ones(p),axis=1)
```

2. list comprehension

You can achieve a similar result by looping over your array in appending. Here a short representation using *list comprehension*.

```
np.stack([np.power(arr,i+1) for i in range(p)],axis=1)
```

Comment: i'm using a dataset like this: arr= np.append(arr, int(a[0])). the values of arr is 1,1,1,2,2... but when I use your code it produces an array with values like this [56.01240149  56.01240149 100.50909784 100.50909784 100.50909784]. do you have any idea why this problem may occur?

Comment: I do not understand what you are writing. Is your comment related to the initial question? Is `arr` the same as in my answer? What is `a`?

Comment: you're right the question was not clear at all, sorry. a is from " for a in dataset: " arr is the name I gave to my array, and its values = 1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4... which are coming from the dataset. i am updating the question with my original code, if you check I'll be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The power/** operator works just like + or *, `broadcasting`:

```
In [136]: arr = np.array([1,2,3])[:,None]
In [137]: arr
Out[137]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
In [138]: arr**np.array([1,2,3,4])
Out[138]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  4,  8, 16],
       [ 3,  9, 27, 81]])
```

For comparison, multiplication

```
In [139]: arr*np.array([1,10,100])
Out[139]: 
array([[  1,  10, 100],
       [  2,  20, 200],
       [  3,  30, 300]])
```

Comment: Has `**` or `np.power()` any advantage over the other or are they equivalent in the internal numpy workings? I would have used the latter, e.g., `np.power(np.asarray(arr)[:, None], np.arange(1, p + 1)[None, :])` for no specific reason.